# Laravel Multi Roles

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-authentication, laravel-admin

I am just new in Laravel 6. I installed the default auth in Laravel. I want to have multiple user.

1. Admin - This user can monitor everything from the dashboard and other pages.
2. Maker - This user can create only a job.
3. Approver - This user can only approve the job but it can't create job.
4. Viewer - This user can only view all the pages of the application.

Other this I need to auto generate an OPGROUP ID for each companies. And I want to the user who is logged in only see what are the data that is save under their account.

Can you help me to achieve my goal please.

Answer (score 0):

We have to follow the below steps

First, we have to create a table by using the below command in which we will store the roles

```
php artisan make: migration create_admins_table --create=admins
```

after creating the migration, we will add the columns

```
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password');
$table->rememberToken(); // I put this linke incase if it was missing
```

then we will run the migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

then we will run the below command

```
php artisan make: model Admin
```

do not forget to add the below code in the admin.php model if there aren't

```
protected $guard = 'admin';
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
```

we have to set up our guard in the **config/auth.php** file
right after the **guards**, we should add the below code

```
'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
'admin-api' => [
                'driver' => 'token',
                'provider' => 'admins',
            ],
```

right after the **provider,** we should add the below code

```
'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
```

let's create controller

```
php artisan make: controller AdminController
```

let's create a view called admin and route in the **web.php**

```
Route::get()'/admin',AdminController@index)
```

and add the below code in the admin controller

```
public function __construct()
            {
                $this->middleware('auth:admin');
            }
```

You can insert user roles in the table (Admin, Maker, Approver, Viewer) and direct it to  views that you want

Comment: Thank you. Follow up question. I am planning to create only 1view on each role. But hide the features or button depend on the role of the user. Is that possible?